# Endpoint publisher in java does not work

Tags: java, web-services

I have the following webservice :

```
package testSmart;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService(name="AddHM", portName="prtNameHM", serviceName="srvNameHM", targetNamespace="hm.com")
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public class add {
    AddBusinessLogic add=new AddBusinessLogic();
    @WebMethod(action="GoAdd", operationName="Go_AddNumber")
    public int addNum(int i, int j) {
        return add.addNum(i, j);
    }
}
```

which works perfectly fine with glassfish.
then I stopped glassfish and use the following code to make my server :

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class publisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:1234/add", new add());
    }
}
```

Now when I try this link:

```
http://localhost:1234/add
```

Nothing happens and the browser says no data received.
Even after trying different port the same problem exist.

Can anyone help me how to fix it?

Comment: isn't it at http://localhost:1234/add/add by chance? :)

Comment: @MarianP thank you but no did not work :)

Answer (score 0):

Call to `http://localhost:1234/add` will not get you anything because there is no specific document with that URI that browser can get. But if you type
`http://localhost:1234/add?wsdl`
you should get the generated wsdl document.